# Issue with routing on my Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

I'm facing the following error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "casanet_addpaperpage" as such route does not exist.") in "CasanetBundle:Admin:deliverables.html.twig" at line 38.

Here is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace ProjectB\CasanetBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use ProjectB\CasanetBundle\Entity\Paper;
use ProjectB\CasanetBundle\Entity\Event;
use ProjectB\CasanetBundle\Entity\Conference;
use ProjectB\CasanetBundle\Entity\Project;
use ProjectB\CasanetBundle\Form\PaperType;

class AdminController extends Controller {

public function deliverablesAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $papers = $em->getRepository("CasanetBundle:Paper")->findAll();
    $events = $em->getRepository("CasanetBundle:Event")->findAll();
    $conferences = $em->getRepository("CasanetBundle:Conference")->findAll();
    $projects = $em->getRepository("CasanetBundle:Project")->findAll();

    return $this->render('CasanetBundle:Admin:deliverables.html.twig', array(
        "papers" => $papers,
        "events" => $events,
        "conferences" => $conferences,
        "projects" => $projects,
    ));
} 

public function addpaperAction(Request $request){
    $paper = new Paper();

    $formPaper = $this->createForm(new PaperType(), $paper);

    if($request->isMethod("POST")){
        $formPaper->handleRequest($request);
        if($formPaper->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $paper = $formPaper->getData();
            $em->persist($paper);
            $em->flush();
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute("casanet_deliverablespage");
    }

    return $this->render('CasanetBundle:Admin:addpaper.html.twig', array(
        "formPaper" => $formPaper->createView(), 
    ));

}
}
```

Here is the concerned route in my routing.yml file:

```
casanet_addpaperpage:
    path:     /admin/addpaper
    defaults: { _controller: CasanetBundle:Admin:addpaper }
```

I've tried clearing the cache, running composer updates,renaming the route, routing through other paths, and so far no results.

Can anyone hint me towards the right way?

EDIT: Here's the concerned segment of my view:

```
<a href="{{path("casanet_addpaperpage") }}" class="btn btn-primary">Add a paper</a>
```

Comment: Have you imported your bundle routing file to `config/routing.yml` and try `php app/console router:debug` to view your routes and confirm the desired route exists.

Comment: It indeed shows up on the console among the other routes after running the routing debug, I suppose it does exist then.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's because your shortname for your bundle isn't right, should be

```
casanet_addpaperpage:
    path:     /admin/addpaper
    defaults: { _controller: ProjectBCasanetBundle:Admin:addpaper }
```

Comment: The shortname is correct, as I forgot to concatenate the bundle name with namespace when it asked me to define the shortname during the generation of the bundle. The other routes who bear the same shortname work successfully aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Since your route is present in router:debug --env=dev then you probably just need to clear the cache.

```
 php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
```

or prod if you use prod.

Comment: No results :/ Cleared cache and restarted all related services, no luck

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.

I ran a composer no-dev update and interrupted it 1 day ago, and it corrupted. Today I updated to Symfony 2.6.5 and it solved the issue I suppose. Thanks everyone!